# Use Android .so in Java code

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Good day. I have a library .so that works well on x86 Android.
How to use this library in Java?

```
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("32");
```

> true

```
static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("full/path/to/library/liblibrary.so");
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   full/path/to/library/liblibrary.so in java.library.path

Maybe it use some library from Android NDK?

Comment: If you have the full path, you could use ```System.load``` instead of ```loadLibrary```. The string you put into ```loadLibrary``` gets mapped to a platform specific library name. You can see the result of this by calling ```System.mapLibraryName```. iirc, on linux, "library" would get mapped to "liblibrary.so".

Comment: Thx. System.load - work. But now a new error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: library.so: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x34) on a AMD 64-bit platform
I also try on x86 JVM
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: library.so: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x34) on a IA 32-bit platform

Comment: I can't help with that... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to System.loadLibrary is a library name chosen arbitrarily by the programmer. The system follows a standard, but platform-specific, approach to convert the library name to a native library name. For example, a Solaris system converts the name pkg_Cls to libpkg_Cls.so, while a Win32 system converts the same pkg_Cls name to pkg_Cls.dll

More from here [at Oracle's JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html)